# Assigning restrictions to rational solutions from Solve/Reduce/FindInstance

Tags: equation-solving

I want to restrict the outputs of `Solve/Reduce/FindInstance`, etc. to "simple" rationals, which I define as rationals of the form:

$$\pm \dfrac{a}{b}\; \text{ where } \; a, b \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\},$$

e.g., $ \tfrac{3}{5}$, $5$, $-\tfrac{4}{3}$, etc.

Since MMA associates the sign with the numerator, e.g.:

```
g = -3/4;
Numerator@g
Denominator@g
```

> -3
>
> 4

... I believe restrictions on rationals can be represented as follows:

```
g = -3/4;
h = 5;
-6 <= Numerator@g <= 6 && 1 <= Denominator@g <= 6
0 <= Numerator@g <= 6 && 1 <= Denominator@g <= 6
0 <= Numerator@h <= 6 && Denominator@h == 1
-6 <= Numerator@h <= 6 && 2 <= Denominator@h <= 6
```

> True
>
> False
>
> True
>
> False

However, `Solve`, `Reduce`, and `FindInstance` don't recognize this. For example:

```
exprA = p + ρ + σ == 0 && -p + r + 2 ν - 3 ρ == 
0 && -2 p - ν - 2 σ == 1
```

[image]

```
FindInstance[
 exprA && -6 <= Numerator@σ <= 6 &&  1 <= Denominator@σ <= 6 
 && -6 <= Numerator@ν <= 6 &&  1 <= Denominator@ν <= 6 
 && -6 <= Numerator@r <= 6 && 1 <= Denominator@r <= 6 
 && -6 <= Numerator@p <= 6 && 1 <= Denominator@p <= 6 
 && -6 <= Numerator@ρ <= 6 && 1 <= Denominator@ρ <= 6,
 {σ, ν, r, p, ρ}, Rationals, 2]
```

[image]

With fewer variables (say, 3 instead of 5), I could instead brute-force the restriction by explicitly reformatting each variable as the ratio of sub-variables, applying value and domain restrictions to each—e.g., replacing the variable $r$ with $\frac{r_1}{r_2}$, where $-6 \leq r_1 \leq 6$, $1 \leq r_2 \leq 6$, $r_1\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r_2\in \mathbb{Z}$.  One can then use `Table` or `Map` to recombine the sub-variables in the output into rational solutions for the variables, and delete the duplicates.  E.g.:

```
exprB = -((3 r1)/r2) - ν1/ν2 + σ1/σ2 == 0 && 
  r1/r2 + ν1/ν2 == 0 && -((2 ν1)/ν2) == 1
```

[image]

```
soln = Solve[
   exprB && {σ1, σ2, ν1, ν2, r1, r2} ∈ Integers && 
    And @@ Thread[-6 <= {σ1, σ2, ν1, ν2, r1, 
        r2} <= 6], {σ1, σ2, ν1, ν2, r1, r2}];
tab = DeleteDuplicates@
  Table[soln[[j, i, 2]]/soln[[j, i + 1, 2]], {j, 1, Length@soln}, {i, 
    1, Length@soln[[1]] - 1, 2}];
TableForm[tab, TableHeadings -> {None, {"σ", "ν", "r"}}]
```

[image]

However, this method doesn't work with `exprA`, since its five variables become 10, making the calculation take too long. [I stopped the following after it ran for 24 hours on my 2019 i9 iMac without producing a result.] Thus it would be nice if there were a way to apply the restrictions directly to the original rational-valued variables, rather than transforming them to ratios of integer-valued variables and thus doubling their number:

```
exprC = exprA /. {σ -> (σ1/σ2), ν -> (ν1/ν2), 
 r -> (r1/r2), p -> (p1/p2), ρ -> (ρ1/ρ2)}
```

[image]

```
soln = Solve[
  exprC && 
   And @@ Thread[-6 <= {σ1, σ2, ν1, ν2, r1, r2, 
       p1, p2, ρ1, ρ2} <= 
      6] && {σ1, σ2, ν1, ν2, r1, r2, p1, 
     p2, ρ1, ρ2} ∈ 
    Integers, {σ1, σ2, ν1, ν2, r1, r2, p1, 
   p2, ρ1, ρ2}]
tab = DeleteDuplicates@
   Table[soln[[j, i, 2]]/soln[[j, i + 1, 2]], {j, 1, Length@soln}, {i,
      1, Length@soln[[1]] - 1, 2}];
TableForm[tab, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"σ", "ν", "r", "p", "ρ"}}]
```

Comment: Why you not simply solve `FindInstance[exprA, {\[Sigma], \[Nu], r, p, \[Rho]}, Rationals, 2]`and then pick the solutions you want?

Comment: @DanielHuber I want all solutions that satisfy my constraints: All numbers are of of the form: $\pm \dfrac{a}{b}$, where a, b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. If you try running`FindInstance[exprA, {\[Sigma], \[Nu], r, p, \[Rho]}, Rationals, 2]`, you'll see it gives two solutions, neither of which satisfy my constraints:  {{\[Sigma] -> -(67/29), \[Nu] -> 6, r -> -(78/29), 
  p -> -(69/58), \[Rho] -> 7/2}, {\[Sigma] -> 101/34, \[Nu] -> 137/34,
   r -> -6, p -> -(373/68), \[Rho] -> 171/68}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why `Numerator` and `Denominator` do not work in `Solve` or `FindInstance`?

Because for symbolic input, they get immediately evaluated:

```
Numerator[x]
(* x *)

Denominator[x]
(* 1 *)
```

Therefore, `Solve` and `FindInstance` don't even see them:

```
Solve[Numerator[x] == 3, x] // Trace // Column
(* {{Numerator[x],x},x==3}
   Solve[x==3,x]
   {{x->3}}
   {{x->3,x->3},{x->3}}
   {{x->3}} *)
```

This explains why some solutions may seem wrong at first sight:

```
FindInstance[Numerator[x] > 1 && Numerator[x] < 20, x, Rationals]
(* {{x -> 21/2}} *)
```

Given my explanation above (or using `Trace`), you can convince yourself that the code is actually equivalent to

```
FindInstance[x > 1 && x < 20, x, Rationals]
```

and the corresponding result $21/2$ is correct.

### Alternative solution

Using `Solve` (or `Reduce`):

```
Solve[exprA]
(* {{ν -> 3 + 2 p - 2 r, ρ -> 2 + p - r, σ -> -2 - 2 p + r}} *)
```

we determine that there are only two independent variables ($p$ and $r$). Therefore, we can enumerate all possible $p$ and $r$, and then perform filtering on the other three variables:

```
sol1 = First@Solve[exprA];
fracs = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Table[m a/b, {m, {1, -1}}, {a, 1, 6}, {b, 1, 6}];
pqs = {p -> #1, r -> #2} & @@@ Tuples[fracs, {2}]; 
sols = {ν, ρ, σ, p, r} /. sol1 /. # & /@ pqs;

solsFiltered = Select[sols, ContainsAll[fracs, #] &]
(* {{3, 2, -3, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -2, 1, 2}, {2, 3/2, -(5/2), 1, 3/2}, ...} *)

Length[solsFiltered]
(* 234 *)
```

Comment: Nice use of algebra to make the problem tractable for MMA. Any idea why `Solve`, etc., don't accept `Numerator` or `Denominator` constraints as restrictions in equalities or inequalities?  As I mentioned above, MMA does return `True` or `False` when those restrictions are applied outside of those functions.

Comment: @theorist, please see my edit.